# How to prove spherical harmonics are orthogonal

Tags: orthonormal, spherical-harmonics

A lot of texts and derivations [eg here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/lectures/node75.html) simply say:

"The Spherical Harmonics are orthonormal, so:

$$
\int{ Y_l^m Y_{l'}^{m'} } = \delta_{ll'}\delta_{mm'}
$$

And if you try any (l,m) pair you will find this always works out.

But how do you *prove* they are orthonormal *for every* $l$ and $m$?  Where do you start? What principles do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe not really an answer but you may get the idea nontheless: this is true more or less by construction. You get the spherical harmonics (as an example) as eigenfunctions of the angular part of the Laplace Operator, that is, they satisfy 
$$\Delta_{S^2} Y_{lm}(\vartheta,\phi) = \lambda Y_{lm} (\vartheta,\phi)$$
(Actually it turns out that this implies $\lambda = -l(l+1)$ with integer $l$)
If you have such eigenfunctions for different eigenvalues it is a matter of linear algebra to show they are orthogonal, by looking at $$\int_{S^2}\langle \nabla_{S^2}Y_{lm}, \nabla_{S^2}Y_{l'm'}\rangle d\mu_{S^2}= -\int_{S^2}\langle Y_{lm}, \Delta_{S^2}Y_{l'm'}\rangle d\mu_{S^2}$$
This implies that the functions are orthogonal if $l\neq l'$, since otherwise you could derive $l(l+1) = l'(l'+1)$ from this. For fixed $l$ it turns out that you may solve the equation by a separation approach which leads to an ODE which is known to be solvable by orthogonal polynomials by ODE theory.

You can also write down the $Y_{ml}$ quite explicitly, see e.g. the german wikipedia page on "Kugelflächenfunktionen" http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelfl%C3%A4chenfunktionen.
If you look at these more closely and and do have some ODE background you may notice that the $\vartheta$ part are well known orthogonal polynomials in $\cos(\vartheta)$ (Legendre Polynomials), while the $\phi$ part is more or less just $e^{im\phi}$ which is known to a system of orthogonal functions. To then actually prove orthogonality is still a bit of work, but it kind of shows you the direction you should take.

To make them actually *orthonormal* you have to norm them, of course, that's where the complicated looking factors come from.

Comment: Neat answer.  I was not aware it was by construction!  So there isn't a way to write an explicit proof, starting with $Y_l^m$.

Comment: Sure there is. That's what I wanted to say with the 'You can also write down...' part. It's just a bit tedious.